# Convert binary, octal, hexa FLOATS to decimal "manually" (ex: [135.263]B10 -> [?]B2)

Tags: math, binary, type-conversion, radix

I'm a student in programmation and I have a course called "*Informatic Mathematics*". In the exercices it's asked to convert floating numbers from decimal, octal, hexadecimal or binary to another base (not necesserly to base 10) and keep 12 digits after the comma(or the dot) if it is possible. 
For exemple:

> (`135.263`)b10 => b2
>   (`100101001.11`)b2 => b10
>   (`1011110010.0101`)b2 => b8
>   ...

I know how to convert numbers. The way I convert the decimal part (after the dot) is to divide this part by the highest multiple of the target base until I get 0 or until I reach the 12th digits after the dot. The problem is that I don't know all the negate multiples of 2 so usually I write them on a separate sheet, but usually I don't have to keep 12 digits after the dot and writing these multiples on a seperate sheet takes time and during the exam, time is a precious thing and I can't waste it to write these multiples.

So I would like to know if there's a better way to do these conversions or if anyone has any tips.

Also, when I convert from non-decimal number to another non-decimal number (ex: b2 => b8) I usually convert the first number to base 10 and then convert the base 10 number to the target base. I would like to know if there's a way to convert the first number directly into the target base without having to convert it in base 10 first.

BTW: Sorry if my english is a bit weird. I'm a french canadian and I did my best, but please let me know if there is something you do not understand well.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with b2 > b8.

001 011 110 010.010 100

As you see, I've separated the number into 3 digit segments (2^3 = 8). You have to add extra 0 to the left and to the right to make it like that. Then you convert it digit by digit. In this case you'll receive 1352.24

b2 => b10
Some harder math here. Mark digits in your number this way:

1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 .  1  1

8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0   -1  -2

Then calculate fractional and whole part
2^0 + 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^8 + 2^-1 + 2^-2

b10 => b2

Multiple the fraction by 2 till you get 1. From each multiplication you take the whole part. Example:
0.25 * 2 = 0.5; 0.5 * 2 = 1;
Thus, 0.25 is 0.01;

**UPD** For negative conversions check out first and second complement.

Comment: I dont understand the fractional part. From what I understand, if I take for exemple '100101001.11' I would have to do this for the fractional part:



'0.5*2=1' 
'0.25*2 = 0.5*2=1'
but what I do with this?

Comment: For .11 example first 1 is power -1, and second one is power -2. Thus you calculate 2 ^ -1 + 2^ -2

Comment: For decimal fractions, you multiple fractional part by 2 and write down the very first number. One more example: 0.625. You have 0.625 * 2 = 1.250. You write down 1 from here. Then you do 0.250 * 2 = 0.5, write down 0. Then 0.5 * 2  = 1. You receive 0.101. If you have 6.625, first you convert 6, it's 110, and then 0.625; you have to get 110.101 in the end.

Comment: ok thanks but do you know any better way to convert form b10 to b2 (ex: 132.263 to b2)?

Comment: The better way is to write a program, and don't do it by hand :)